# SQL query for room availability check

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an online room reservation system.

One of the tables of the database is supposed to hold the bookings. It has an autonumber field, customer data fields, two date fields for arrival and departure, and anther table booking details have: bookedid, roomid and room count.

A search page submits the arrival and departure dates to a result page which is then supposed to tell the customer how many rooms are available within the period if any. This is where it all goes wrong. I just can't get an accurate count of the number of rooms already booked within the period requested.

**Bookings table**

```
id|guest  | arrive     | depart      
1 |Smith  | 2017-12-20 | 2017-12-25  
2 |Jones  | 2017-12-21 | 2017-12-25  
3 |Brown  | 2017-12-23 | 2017-12-27  
4 |White  | 2017-12-24 | 2017-12-26
```

**Booking Details table**

```
id     | booked_id | room_id |room_count
1      | 1         |  1      | 2
2      | 1         |  2      | 2
3      | 2         |  1      | 4
4      | 3         |  2      | 2
5      | 3         |  1      | 2
6      | 4         |  1      | 2
```

**Rooms table** - Room `room_id` comes from here.

```
room_id | type        | count   |amount
1       | Single room |  10     | 1000
2       | Deluxe room |  5      | 2000
```

I want a particular rooms availability (for eg:room_id is 1)

```
date        available     roomid
2017-12-20  |   8      |  1
2017-12-21  |   4      |  1
2017-12-22  |   4      |  1
2017-12-23  |   2      |  1
2017-12-24  |   0      |  1
2017-12-25  |   0      |  1
2017-12-26  |   4      |  1
2017-12-27  |   8      |  1
2017-12-28  |   10     |  1
2017-12-25  |   10     |  1
```

I am also using calender table. and i have written a query like

```
SELECT x.dt , r.room_cnt - COALESCE(SUM(d.`booking_cnt`),0) available
FROM calendar_table x
LEFT JOIN bookings y ON x.dt >= y.`date_from` AND x.dt < y.`date_to`
LEFT JOIN booking_details d ON d.booking_id=y.id
LEFT JOIN rooms r ON r.id= 1
WHERE x.dt BETWEEN now()  AND now() + interval 3 month GROUP BY dt
```

But this is not working properly.

Comment: There is no way to link the guest to the booked room, maybe you should show the structure of the calendar table too.

Comment: I'm guessing this line `< y.date_to` needs to say `<= y.date_to` so it includes the last day of the reservation.

Comment: `x.dt  between y.date_from AND y.date_to` should also work.

Comment: Aside: questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the query like this,

```
SELECT x.dt , r.room_cnt,SUM(d.`booking_cnt`) booked,r.room_cnt- SUM(d.`booking_cnt`) available FROM calendar_table x
LEFT JOIN bookings y ON x.dt >= y.`date_from` AND x.dt < y.`date_to`
LEFT JOIN booking_details d ON d.booking_id=y.id and d.room_id='1'
LEFT JOIN rooms r ON r.id= 1
WHERE x.dt BETWEEN now()-interval 3 month AND now() + interval 3 month GROUP BY dt
```

Comment: This looks helpful. To make it even better (and as general advice for your future answers), would you consider adding an explanation of what you changed? What was your strategy/approach? Future readers are best served if their attention is drawn to the critical difference between code in an answer and code in a question. Thanks!